# Build Failed - Non-Zero Exit Code Detected after 'npm build' in AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, gatsby, aws-amplify

I am linked my AWS Amplify app to a new React Gatsby GitHub repo for continuous deployment. The app compiles fine locally, but I am getting an error in the 'Frontend' during the AWS build, saying that the amplify.sh file is 'killed' at the npm run build line, followed by 'Non-Zero Exit Code Detected' error. Below is a link to a screenshot of the error:

[AWS Amplify Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IJLO.png)

Below are the contents of my amplify.yml file in AWS:

```html
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: public
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Do I need to edit the amplify.yml file, or maybe add something to a package-lock or gatsby-node file?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by running `npm install` (locally) and push to the branch. The error was invalid `package-lock` file version.

This was the step suggested in the build fail log.

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks fine.

Would you be able to confirm that the IAM Role 'AWSAmplifyExecutionRole' has the AdministratorAccess permission? In order to do a CloudFormation deploy the role needs that permission in order to create all the resources in the stack.

**OR**

Please share the error log content, if possible.